# -bash: child setpgid (236 to 235): Operation not permitted (on WSL opensuse)

Tags: bash, opensuse, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On WSL (opensuse Leap 42.3), I encountered a bug like this:

```
$ echo "$*" | sed "s $HOME ~ g"
```

> -bash: child setpgid (236 to 235): Operation not permitted

This is not the case on the default Leap 42.3, I suspect that this is a bug
of WSL(opensuse Leap 42.3). I am using Windows10 Pro 64bit.

Comment: On Wed Feb 28 19:17:50 DST 2018, the bug fixed by somebody. I'm okay with it, thanks.